# exchange 2010 mailbox issue

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010

Environment - CAS Array - with 2 CAS/Hub Transport servers.  DAG with 2 MBX servers.

Issue - just a couple of users have an issue where their outlook will stop communicating with exchange, usually when sending a messasge. The outlook client does not freeze up, it gets stuck on status updating.

When viewing the users mailbox, via EMC the properties dialog box will freeze when checking the "Mailbox Features Tab". Also when tyring to move the mailbox to another DB store it times out.

Can not find any related errors in the logs at the time of the issue.

*update* - The re-created profile did not help. Nor did SCANPST. It appears that the issue occurs after a big update to the mailbox, for example.. the user deletes 300 messages in their inbox. The client then hangs on status - "updating"

Comment: Sounds like a client issue.  Blame user/user's machine and punt to the helldesk.

Comment: some of the problems he's list are not client problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A combination of a network upgrade and Stopping AV services have resolved this problem

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with HopelessN00b.

Try:

- Window Updates, SP etc.
- Run SCANPST (likely issues with PST, will take awhile
  depending on # of emails)
- New Profile Does it happen in Safe Mode? if
  not, then likely a plugin issue
- Try "Outlook.exe /cleanviews". This
  will reset to all folder views to default
- Disable AV/Anti-spam on client machine and see if problem persist

Comment: The affected user is having their Profile recreated. I will also run the SCANPST as well, and the others you mentioned. Will post back later with results. Appreciate the help!

Comment: The re-created profile did not help. Nor did SCANPST. It appears that the issue occurs after a big update to the mailbox, for example.. the user deletes 300 messages in their inbox. The client then hangs on status - "updating"

Comment: Going to open up a new post, with a more accurate depiction of the problem, now that I have newer information

Comment: New question can be found at 

http://serverfault.com/questions/457067/exchange-2010-slow-performance


I will be deleting this question soon